# Bringing _variation_description from WooCommerce into ShipStation

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to bring text from the Description field in my product variations into Custom Field 2 in my ShipStation orders. I've followed this function from WooCommerce but not seeing anything in ShipStation yet. Grateful for any suggestions.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );
function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
return '_variation_description';
}
```

Comment: The hook you are using is used for order meta data, but NOT for product meta data or even order item meta data…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you. Is it at all possible to bring product meta data over into the custom field?

Comment: NO, this hook is only for order meta data (and not order items or product meta data)